# Docker on windows 7: hello-world runs on Docker Quickstart Terminal but not on command prompt. why?

Tags: docker, windows-7, docker-compose, docker-machine, windows-7-embedded

I haven't been able to run hello-world on command prompt but on quickstart terminal it works. Why is that? Error message on command prompt:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rw5s9roTIiWnpOM1JhVUNDZVU/view?usp=sharing

In a broader context, I am trying to run Docker compose to set up a network but unsuccessful. So I figure understanding more about Docker would be helpful. Appreciate any pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please copy paste the error directly in your post)

From the screenshot, you run this command from Windows system. Did you install `docker for windows` in your windows system? To do this, you need check if your windows system is good enough to do that. [Check Windows versions of Docker Engine, Compose, and Machine](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

If you installed `Docker for Windows`, then you should be fine to `docker run hello-world` directly.

Otherwise, you should choice to run with windows base image, lucky Docker company made this.

```
docker run run hello-world:nanoserver
```

You can compare the differences about `hello-world:latest` and `hello-world:nanoserver`

Dockerfile for image `hello-world:nanoserver`:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
COPY hello.txt C:
CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
```

Dockerfile for image `hello-world:latest`

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Comment: thanks, tried running it with nanoserver, and come with following error message: C:\Users\User>docker run run hello-world:nanoserver
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.29/c
ontainers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file s
pecified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must
 be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon
 is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not supported natively on Windows7. It run in virtual box 'boot2docker' which provides it a linux environmental. The quickstart terminal is a special bash environment instead of the standard Windows command prompt, so you can't run docker commands on Windows command prompt.

Pointer-> https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#what-you-get-and-how-it-works

However Docker is natively supported on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed Docker Toolbox, for Windows versions prior to 10. I am curious why I could run it in quickstart [$ docker run hello-world], and not on cmd [docker run hello-world] . However, I am still trying to figure out how to make it work on command prompt, and further to set up a network. Thanks again for your tip!